# как задать массив Numpy в Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Пытаюсь освоить cython и ООП. Написал код:

```
import numpy as np
N = 10
import cython_001
cython_001.test(1, N)
```

Для него написал cython:

```
cpdef int test(int x, int N):
    import numpy as np
    cdef int i
    y = np.arange(N, dtype='float64')
    for i in range(N):
        y[i] = i
    print(y[5])
    return y
```

Появляется сообщение:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
Exception ignored in: 'cython_001.test'
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

1. Как правильно задать тип массива numpy 'y'?
2. Как в будущем задать двумерный массив?

Comment: Зачем вам эта белиберда и там и там numpy?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1153426/312941

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [вопрос по Cython](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1153426/%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-cython)

Comment: Удалил предыдущий комментарий, чтобы не было дублирования